# Change Stroke Style of a Simple fill Symbol Selector with PyQGIS

Tags: symbology, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

How do i change the Stroke Style of a simple fill with python ?
Here is a picture that i want to change ?
[image]

Here is my code :

```
    processing.run('native:buffer', {"INPUT": delta, "DISTANCE":QgsProperty.fromExpression("bande"), "OUTPUT": "memory"})
    blayer=QgsVectorLayer("MultiPolygon?crs=epsg:2154", "Bande Etude", "memory")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(blayer)
    blayer_feat= blayer.getFeatures()
    blayer.startEditing()
    j=0
    for feat in blayer_feat :
      blayer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), 1, delta_t[j])
      j=j+1
    target_field = 'delta_t'

    myRangeList = []

    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(blayer.geometryType())
    symbol.setColor(QColor("#f7fbff"))
    symbol.setOpacity(0.6)
    #symbol(0).setStrokeStyle(Qt.PenStyle(Qt.NoPen))
    myRange = QgsRendererRange(0, 10.0, symbol, '0 a 10')
    myRangeList.append(myRange)

    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(blayer.geometryType())
    symbol.setColor(QColor("#08306b"))
    symbol.setOpacity(0.6)
    myRange = QgsRendererRange(10.1, 100.0, symbol, '10 a 100')
    myRangeList.append(myRange)

    myRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer(target_field, myRangeList)
    myRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.Custom)

    blayer.setRenderer(myRenderer)
    blayer.setFeatureBlendMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Darken
```

I've tried a line code like : symbol(0).setStrokeStyle(Qt.PenStyle(Qt.NoPen)) but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you need to use `symbolLayer(0)` and not `symbol(0)`:

```
...
symbol.setOpacity(0.6)
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeStyle(Qt.PenStyle(Qt.NoPen))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`setStrokeStyle` doesn't work for me,

but `symbol.symbolLayer(0).setPenStyle(Qt.PenStyle(Qt.NoPen))` works.

See: https://api.qgis.org/api/3.22/classQgsSimpleLineSymbolLayer.html#ab938b02769d1a1ff226351b1992cfc1b